# grouping the same value returned by $.each jquery

Tags: jquery

I am returning json objects that turned out to have the same value with them. I would like to avoid repeating the same value and just merged them into on, including the other values that come with them. I have been trying to get the length of the objects with the same value so that I could just do the merge, but I am not getting anywhere. All i am having is the actual length of the value, not how many times they turned up.

```
$.each(data, function(i, val)){
  var city = val.city;
  var name = val.name;
}

<!-- printing the results, they would all like this -->
Los Angeles
  George Martin
Los Angeles 
  Alex Dell
Los Angeles
  Tom Front
Sao Paulo
  Jean Mont
Sao Paulo 
  Steve Bald
```

I want to group them by city. So that it wont look redundant. I have been trying this to work.

```
var newcity = null;
if(newcity !== city){
  city = city;
}
newcity = city;
```

i also try this one, which is absolutely stupid. counting the results for the city

```
var countcityobj = val.city.length;
```

Can anyone guide me on how to do this with jquery? thanks.

Comment: you need to share the json format

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like

```
var map = {};
$.each(data, function (i, rec) {
    var vals = map[rec.city] ? map[rec.city] : map[rec.city] = [];
    vals.push(rec);
});

console.log(map)
//the object map will have the city name as the key ans all the records of the city in an array as the value
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/25XRS/)

Comment: thanks for answering, but i cant see the result in the fiddle.

Comment: did you check the browser console

Comment: hey it worked now, i forgot to open the console for jsfiddle. thanks.